# LC_MESSAGES error in C

Tags: c, locale, string.h

I had been going through the C documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror)

I tried to run the example

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXTl__ l
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(void)
{
FILE *fp = fopen(tmpnam((char[L_tmpnam]){0}), "r");
if (fp==NULL) {
    printf("File opening failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "de_DE.utf8");
    printf("Now in German: %s\n", strerror(errno));

#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXTl__
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.utf8");
    size_t errmsglen = strerrorlen_s(errno) + l;
    char errmsg[errmsglen];
    strerror_s(errmsg, errmsglen, errno);
    printf("Now in Chinese: %s\n", errmsg);
#endif // __STDC_LIB_EXTl__

}
}
```

but I was unable to build it. I got the following error:

> **error: 'LC_MESSAGES' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> ```
>      setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "de_DE.utf8");
>                ^
> ```

How to build it successfully?

Comment: I compiled this code and it compiled for me. We can see that LC_MESSAGES is defined in locale.h and its included in your code. Can you tell your gcc version and compiling statement.

Comment: The version is 5.1.0

Comment: Mine is 4.8.2. Can you try to delete all the lines in the code and just have that one line "setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "de_DE.utf8");" in your main. And the try to complie. It will helpful if you can show us the compile statement that you are using.

Comment: Still not working. On the other hand I tried using LOCALE_ALL instead of LOCALE_MESSAGES, and it did run. Also the error message didn't print in dutch (it was meant to). what do you actually mean by compiling statement? :/

Comment: Just try to do gcc -E filename.c > new.c and then open new.c. In new.c, you should be able to find LC_ALL. Somewhere near you should be able to find LC_MESSAGES. If you are not able to find that then the locale.h version that you have does not have LC_MESSAGES. You can also try to verify by doing man setlocale and that page will show you all the possible options.

Comment: Is the header file locale.h outdated ?